# Accessing individual I/O pin on MSP430

Tags: c, msp430, gpio, software

I'm porting some software from Microchip PIC (using the HI-Tech C Compiler) to TI MSP430, and in the existing code they access the pins directly with something like:

```
RA1 = 1;
```

Is there a similar way to do this with the MSP430, or do I have to write to the entire input/output register each time? If it is not possible has any one come up with a good equivalent? I am using Code Composer Studio v5.3 and the compiler that comes with that.

Comment: [TI's MSPWare](http://www.ti.com/mspware) has got helper functions for controlling the GPIO (although not for all MSP430 sub-families).

Comment: *[moderator note: This comment have arrive to this thread as a result of a merge.]* What's wrong with chapter 8 of the family manual?? Perhaps you should provide an example question of one very specific "manipulation" you'd like to understand how to do. That might go a long way in avoiding forcing us to write and reproduce an entire chapter for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MSP430, accessing individual pins is commonly written using [defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion) and [bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html):

```
P2OUT &= ~BIT1;    /* Pin P2.1 = 0 */
P2OUT |= BIT1;     /* Pin P2.1 = 1 */
P2OUT ^= BIT1;     /* Toggle Pin P2.1 */
```

Be sure to include the proper header file for your specific chip that contains the port and pin (`BIT#`) defines.

Comment: Ok, it looks like for each time I see something like `RA1 = 1;` Im going to have to set the output register each time.

Comment: @Dean Pretty much. The defines just make it easier to read. I occasionally see code online using `P2OUT.BIT1 = 1;` but I don't know if that works or not. In my experience with the MSP430, I've always used bitwise operations to access individual pins. It seems the more common way of doing things.

Comment: If you're using CCS, it should be enough to include `msp430.h`; the compiler will automatically detect which micro you're on.

Answer (score 2):

TI Discussion board had a very [informative discussion](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp43016-bit_ultra-low_power_mcus/f/166/t/61085.aspx) about the same thing.

In short, this is defined by the generic `msp430.h` header used in CCS (which is linked to the specific target chip `msp430xxxx.h` on compile). It does not have support for `PxOUT.BITy` style assignments.

IAR's io430.h does have support for that, but the consensus is that `msp430.h` is the better header (as the `msp430xxxx.h` headers are written by TI employees, `io430.h` is written by IAR employees)

`PxOUT |= BITy` style is the best way to set a single bit.
`PxOUT &= ~BITy` style is the best way to clear a single bit.

Comment: Nitpick: `PxOUT &= ~BITy` **clears** a bit. `PxOUT |= BITy` sets a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is a workaround for individual pin access using Code Composer (with a little tweak can be ported on any compiler). The example is a modified version of the Code Composer Basic Example Blink the LED.
In this example instead of writing the usual statement LED=1 to turn on the LED you will write LED(HI).

```
//***************************************************************************
//
// MSP432 main.c template - P1.0 port toggle
//
//***************************************************************************

#include "msp.h"

#define LO             0x00
#define HI             0x01

#define BIT_0           0x01
#define BIT_1           0x02
#define BIT_2           0x04
#define BIT_3           0x08
#define BIT_4           0x10
#define BIT_5           0x20
#define BIT_6           0x40
#define BIT_7           0x80

#define LED_BIT          BIT_0

#define LED_PORT         P1OUT

#define LED(x) (x==HI)?(LED_PORT |= LED_BIT):(LED_PORT &= ~LED_BIT)

void main(void)
{
volatile uint32_t i;

WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;           // Stop watchdog timer

// The following code toggles P1.0 port
P1DIR |= BIT0;                      // Configure P1.0 as output

while(1)
{

     //blink LED1
                LED(HI);
                _delay_cycles(100000);
                LED(LO);
                _delay_cycles(100000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TI themselves does it like this in one of their examples for the Code Composer Studio (CCS) and IAR compilers:

```
void main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;             // Stop watchdog timer
  P1DIR |= 0x01;                        // Set P1.0 to output direction

  for (;;)
  {
    volatile unsigned int i;

    P1OUT ^= 0x01;                      // Toggle P1.0 using exclusive-OR

    i = 50000;                          // Delay
    do (i--);
    while (i != 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*[moderator note: This comment have arrive to this thread as a result of a merge.]*

*[author note: the original question where I posted this answer stated that no code example could be found]*

Erm okay, it took me around 30 seconds to find this:

[TI website for MSP430F2274](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F2274)

[Tools and Software for MSP430F2274](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F2274/toolssoftware)

[Example code for MSP430F22x4](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slac123&fileType=zip)

And finally there is a folder called `C` and in that you find some files called `msp430x22x4_p1_0x.c` which contain code examples on how to use the Port 1 in C. There is even a readme to tell you which file is used for what.

And to make this answer not completely useless:

```
#include <msp430.h>

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop watchdog timer
  P1DIR |= BIT0;                            // Set P1.0 to output direction

  while (1)                                 
  {
    if ((BIT2 & P1IN) == BIT2)
    {
      P1OUT |= BIT0;                        // if P1.2 set, set P1.0
    }
    else
    {
      P1OUT &= ~(BIT0);                       // else reset
    }
  }
}
```

(Heavily based on `msp430x22x4_p1_01.c` by A. Dannenberg / W. Goh, the complete copyright statement is too big for this answer, but is contained in the linked Code Example file)

Comment: To be complete (as an example) I think you need to also quote the macros (where the memory map 'magic' comes into play), so some fragments of the header file. Not sure if its worth the effort through...

Comment: @SeanHoulihane well yeah I could `*(uint16_t*)(0x1234U) = 0x20U` but nah the compiler will have the header files, so the code should be something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to change the port in bit units, so I wrote a sample code.
I'm glad if you can use it as a reference.

The sample code is for MSP430FR6989.
Rewrite the address if necessary.
The address can be found on the data sheet for each device.

```
typedef unsigned char   _BYTE;

union _BITFIELD {
  _BYTE   BYTE;
  struct {
    _BYTE B7  :1;
    _BYTE B6  :1;
    _BYTE B5  :1;
    _BYTE B4  :1;
    _BYTE B3  :1;
    _BYTE B2  :1;
    _BYTE B1  :1;
    _BYTE B0  :1;
  }       BIT;
};

union un_gpio {                                         /* union GPIO   */
                unsigned char BYTE;                     /*  Byte Access */
                struct {                                /*  Bit  Access */
                       unsigned char B0 :1;             
                       unsigned char B1 :1;             
                       unsigned char B2 :1;             
                       unsigned char B3 :1;             
                       unsigned char B4 :1;             
                       unsigned char B5 :1;             
                       unsigned char B6 :1;             
                       unsigned char B7 :1;             
                       }      BIT;                      
                };

// This is MSP430FR6989 address.
#define GPIO1      (*(volatile union un_gpio    *)0x202)  /* IO    Address*/
#define GPIO2      (*(volatile union un_gpio    *)0x203)  /* IO    Address*/
#define GPIO3      (*(volatile union un_gpio    *)0x222)  /* IO    Address*/
#define GPIO4      (*(volatile union un_gpio    *)0x223)  /* IO    Address*/

/**
 * main.c
 */
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

    //P1SEL &= (~BIT0);           // Set P1.0 SEL for GPIO
    P1DIR |= BIT0;              // Set P1.0 as Output
    P1OUT = 0xFF;

    while(1)
    {
        //GPIO1.BYTE = 0x01;
        GPIO1.BIT.B0 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B1 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B2 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B3 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B4 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B5 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B6 = 1;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B7 = 1;
        //P1OUT = 0x01;

        __delay_cycles(800000);

        //GPIO1.BYTE = 0x00;
        GPIO1.BIT.B0 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B1 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B2 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B3 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B4 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B5 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B6 = 0;
        //GPIO1.BIT.B7 = 0;
        //P1OUT = 0x00;

        __delay_cycles(800000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSP430 can set or clear individual bits via the BIS or BIC (BIt Set) instructions.

So I would certainly expect `P2OUT.BIT1 = 1;` to work in C (at least in mspgcc; the equivalent Ada code does)

```
procedure Blinky is
    LED : Boolean renames p1out_bits(0);
begin
    -- Initialise registers etc simplified out
    loop
        LED := True;
        Delay_MS(200);
        LED := False;
        Delay_MS(800);
    end loop;
end Blinky;
```

Comment: Using bit operations should compile to the same thing when appropriate, even if that syntax isn't defined.